# Android Loading Custom Number Picker Drawable [Image Inside]

Tags: android, numberpicker

On the left is the default Number Picker by android. Is it possible to load a custom number picker like on the right, if I have the drawable images?

[image: NumberPicker]

Comment: If one of these answers has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can customize it like any other widget in android.
you can extend the class and edit it programmaticly or you can use selector.

refer to this tutorial.[custom number picker](http://devmobapps.blogspot.com/2011/09/numberpicker-use-and-customization-of.html)

Comment: Great idea but what if I wanted the number picker to be horizontal?